# Compare each value of two ActiveRecords returning a boolean variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, compare

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I have two ActiveRecord objects of the same class Account like these:

```
# Account1
<Account id: 1, name: "Test name 1", surname: "Test surname 1", email: "...", ...>
```

and

```
# Account2
<Account id: 2, name: "Test name 2", surname: "Test surname 2", email: "...", ...>
```

How to compare in few lines of code each attribute of Account1 with the corresponding attributes of Account2 to test whether the values are equal? I should receive an output of 'true' if all the values of Account1 are equal to those of the Account2, otherwise 'false' even if only one is different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
account1.attributes == account2.attributes
```

There, that's pretty short. Note though that the id is included in those attributes. You could use .clone on both to avoid that, or exclude it from the attributes hash some other way. For example:

```
account1.attributes.except('id') == account2.attributes.except('id')
```

Comment: You don't seem to have read either of the answers. Just using `@ar_object1 == @ar_object2` won't do what you want because they're compared by id, not by the attributes. Try following the suggestions you've been given (mine first, of course :-)

Comment: Dho! I forgot the '. attributes' part! Thanks

Comment: @noodl I used this and it didnt work because it was still comparing the fields created_at and updated_at, easy fix though!

Answer (score 1):

```
(account1.attributes.keys - ["id"]).inject(true) { |memo, att| memo && (account1[att] == account2[att]) }
```